# prestashop 1.5 basic product stock management

Tags: product, prestashop, stock

I'm trying to find product/stock management in prestashop 1.5.0.17.

I've found Advanced Stock Management, but this is not what I want, since I will have just one storehouse with no name and nothing special.

In old prestashop versions (e.g. 1.2) there was just a simple "quantity" input in the product edit form, which did the job. Is there anything like this in new prestashop or I'm forced to use advanced stock management :/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Preferences->Products->Enable stock management->Yes
```

After that you will can set quantities here: `Catalog->Product->Edit->Quantities`

Regards